# Extracting Expression Tree object from String expression in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, tree, stack, expression

In my .Net Core Project, I want to convert a string expression to a Tree class object named Calculation via a method.

First of all, my Calculation class is as follows:

```
public class Calculation
    {
        public bool? CurrentValue { get; set; }
        public Calculation LeftHandValue { get; set; }
        public Calculation RightHandValue { get; set; }
        public Func<bool, bool, bool> Function { get; set; }
    }
```

Let's say I have a string and it's string:

> **(0 | ( 1 & 2 ))**

Its tree is as follows:

```
  |
 / \
0   &
   / \
  1   2
```

The conversion of this string to a Calculation object is as follows:

```
var calc = new Calculation()
            {
                LeftHandValue = new Calculation() { CurrentValue = GetBoolValue(0) },
                RightHandValue = new Calculation()
                {
                    LeftHandValue = new Calculation() { CurrentValue = GetBoolValue(1) },
                    RightHandValue = new Calculation() { CurrentValue = GetBoolValue(2) },
                    Function = (a, b) => a && b
                },
                Function = (a, b) => a || b
            };
```

This string can change. We just & and | We will own the operators. We will use the and ( ) expressions frequently.
I'm adding a few more string expressions:

```
((0 & 1) & 2)
((0 & 2) | (2 & 1)
```

Whatever string comes. I need a method that will extract the Calculation object. Can you help me please?

Comment: What about `1 & 2 & 3` or is that not possible?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: do you monly need `@` and `&`-operators? What about unary expressions, for instance `!`? And what about xor and so on...? Writing an expression-parser is way too broad for a single question here.

Comment: I need only  & and | operator right now.

Comment: Might want to check out https://mathparser.org/

or if want to implement yourself, then you should read:  https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/writing-a-simple-math-expression-engine-in-csharp/